# New OutputDeviceUID is nil msg when instantiating MPVolumeView

Tags: ios, mpvolumeview

Today, likely as a result of upgrading to iOS 12.3 on my test phone, I am now receiving the following notifications in my debug console when I first instantiate my `MPVolumeView`.

> 019-05-21 11:00:22.874353-0600 sports-audio-dj[3831:982163]
>   [MediaRemote] OutputDeviceUID is nil Speaker: (null)

I receive about 10+ of these.

Here is the code that kicks it off:

```
let volumeView = MPVolumeView(frame: self.view.bounds)
```

My code hasn't changed and I'd not seen this before today and wondering if anyone knows what is bringing this about and if I need to do anything about it if something is now unhappy.  My app seems to work fine despite these new notifications.

Comment: Sadly the new iOS v12.3.1 didn't resolve the issue :(

Comment: Has anyone filled a radar for this issue?

Comment: I added one yesterday, WWDC will delay the response but I'll update this when I get one.

Comment: I am also using MPVolumeView and seeing this (iOS 12.3.1). Unfortunately, in my case it seems to be causing some sort of main thread starvation. My UI may not update for as much as 5 seconds while these are firing in the console. I am looking for a workaround, but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Given the response Apple gave me you may be waiting until iOS 13 is out in the Fall.

Answer (score 15):

Apple responded today with the following:

You can safely ignore this debugging message. It will be removed in a future version of iOS.

Comment: yes i agree with this. i haven't change anything except my xcode version. it's a new version library warning about something inside their library code or something like that. i don't know. but i know that i haven't change a single code.

Comment: These debug messages are still alive and well in iOS 12.4 :(

Comment: These debug messages are still alive and well in iOS 12.4.1

Answer (score 2):

iOS 13 has finally removed these errant debug messages.